# Does function overloading have runtime overhead in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, overloading

Is there any additional runtime overhead in calling overloaded functions?

(I ask this specifically for Delphi, in case the answer isn't the same for all compiled languages)

I think not as that should be resolved during compile time, but you can never be sure can you?

Answer (score 19):

Of course you can be sure, because it is [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions).  Is the compiler which resolves it at compile time, so there's no additional overhead on calling overloaded functions in Delphi.

[Edit]

I did a small test for you:

```
var
  j: Integer;
  st: string;

procedure DoNothing(i: Integer); overload;
begin
  j := i;
end;

procedure DoNothing(s: string); overload;
begin
  st := s;
end;

procedure DoNothingI(i: integer);
begin
  j := i;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  MaxIterations = 10000000;
var
  StartTick, EndTick: Cardinal;
  I: Integer;
begin
  StartTick := GetTickCount;
  for I := 0 to MaxIterations - 1 do
    DoNothing(I);
  EndTick := GetTickCount;
  Label1.Caption := Format('Overlaod ellapsed ticks: %d [j:%d]', [EndTick - StartTick, j]);
  StartTick := GetTickCount;
  for I := 0 to MaxIterations - 1 do
    DoNothingI(I);
  EndTick := GetTickCount;
  Label1.Caption := Format('%s'#13'Normal ellapsed ticks: %d [j:%d]', [Label1.Caption, EndTick - StartTick, j]);
end;
```

Result: Almost all the time 31 Ticks (milliseconds) for both on my dev machine, sometimes overload takes only 16 ticks.

[image]

Comment: Right.  There's a (negligible) amount of compile-time overhead, but none at runtime.

Comment: The compiled code does not care about the name but the address of the right procedure to call. Since this translation name => address is done at compile time, in the end, at run time, it is exactly the same as having different names.

Comment: Don't use tickcount! Because most time functions works in steps of 15ms! E.g. sleep(1) = 15ms, but also the Now() function! That's why sometimes 31 ticks and sometimes 16 ticks.

Comment: Better use QueryPerformanceCounter, this one is the best (about 3Mhz) so you can count microseconds

Comment: @André: `GetTickCount()` is perfectly fine for such quick tests, provided the measured time is large compared to the resolution (just make `MaxIterations` large enough to result in a few 100 ms runtime).

Comment: GetTickCount is not efficient for these kind of tests, so your results aren't valid. 
Check for other timer counter:
http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-high-performance-timer-tstopwatch.htm

Comment: I didn't understood. Did you say of course it have runtime overhead?

Comment: @SaCi, the first paragraph states: "there's no additional overhead on calling overloaded functions in Delphi".  As for the timing, feel free to change for what you think is more accurate in your own tests.  GetTickCount is good for me in this case.

Comment: About the time counting, this result is the variance of imprecision of the GetTickCount, the result have no link with the real time spent. Read more in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @SaCi everyone here, including me, agree that GetTickCount is not the more accurate time measuring function, but for this small test it seems OK to me.  FYI, changing the time measure in this example to QueryPerformanceCount shows a two msecs variation against GetTickCount measure on my laptop, which is OK to me.  The important part which is to show both calls take almost the same time (overload vs. not overload) is accurate using both.

Comment: Everyone not, André saw the same problem. "The important part which is to show both calls take almost the same time", you can't affirm this using  GetTicketCount, if you are measuring a overhead that can be nanoseconds you can't use a function that have 32ms of imprecision. But is ok, if you say that a performance test that the result is the variance error of the method of counting is ok to your tests, so is ok. In my vision, it isn't, 'cause even the test is small the test must return the correct value, 'cause it's a performance test. To me, is like measure centimeters with a meter rule.

Comment: @SaCi, for me (and others) it is OK of you measure 10 million centimeters with a meter rule, just look at the code. :D

Comment: But in this case the 'centimeters' doesn't reachs half of a meter :D But it's ok, others users can take there own conclusion with our  replies. Bey, until other post :)

Answer (score 3):

Overloading is resolved at compile time (no overhead), but overriding has overhead!
`virtual` is faster than `dynamic`:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods

> Virtual versus Dynamic
>   In Delphi for Win32, virtual and dynamic methods are semantically equivalent.
>   However, they differ in the implementation of method-call dispatching at run time: virtual methods optimize for speed, while dynamic methods optimize for code size.